In a geodesic triangle, is the longest side opposite to the largest angle?
If I have a complete (smooth) Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and three points on it, that I connect with distance minimizing geodesics, will the longest edge be opposite to the largest angle?
In Euclidean geometry, this is a consequence of the law of sines, so this was my first ansatz. But it seems that the law of sines only generalizes to manifolds with constant curvature.
A reference would be enough.

This will be false. You can even arrange the angle opposite to the longest side to be arbitrarily close to zero.

This is an interesting question for constant-curvature spaces and two-point homogeneous spaces (a.k.a. rank 1 symmetric spaces). Note that even in the flat case, the proof is not entirely trivial, because the sine function does not happen to be monotone on the interval $[0,\pi]$ :-)  One needs to consider two separate cases: (1) an acute triangle (for which the proof using the sine formula goes through smoothly) and (2) an obtuse triangle, in which case one can use the generalized Pythagorean formula (the law of cosines) to show that the generalized hypotenuse is longer than the other sides.

Already in the spherical case, the same argument cannot go through because a geodesic triangle can have three obtuse angles.  Perhaps I am missing something obvious but I don't see a one-step proof, even though "morally" this should be true in the constant curvature case.  @MoisheKohan

Thank you very much for your insightful comments. I guess a triangle with the two shorter sides shaped as "}" would be a counter example. I need to think more about the constant curvature case.

Here is an argument that works in the constant curvature case.  Consider the circle inscribed in the triangle $ABC$.  The points of contact of the inscribed circle with the sides of the
triangle partition these sides into six segments of pairwise
equal lengths $a,a,b,b,c,c$.  Thus $|AB|=a+b$, $|BC|=b+c$, and
$|CA|=c+a$.  Denoting by $A$ the largest angle, it is easy to see that
the length $a$ is the shortest of the three lengths $a,b,c$.
Therefore the side $|BC|=b+c$ opposite the vertex $A$ is the longest side.
It would be interesting to see if this type of argument generalizes to
rank 1 symmetric spaces.
